# Why does Orion Context Broker not return all the entities expected by a query with a pattern expression?

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware, fiware-wirecloud

Some days ago when I made a query to Orion context broker with regular expressions, the response included all the entities that match that regular expression, now only retrieve the data of the older entities and if i want to access to the most recent entities, I need to make another request with a more specific regular expression.

The problem is that now I need to make two different querys with differents regular expression to retrieve the old and new entities when a week ago I only had to make one with the most generic regular expression.

Imagine that the structure of the id of my entities are:

- **dev:name_proyect:name_object:name_service**

Some days ago I only need this generic expression to retrieve all the data:

- **dev:name_proyect:.***

Now I need two queryes to obtain the same result:

- **dev:name_proyect:.*** -> the response only include old entities
- **dev:name_proyect:name_object:.*** ->the response retrieve only the new data

So, the use of regular expression have changed in Orion CB? I need to do something else now to retrieve all the data with only one query with the most  generic regular expression?

The instance of Orion that I am using is:
http://orion.lab.fi-ware.eu:1026

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that since 0.14.0, Orion implements pagination, which details are described in [the corresponding section in the user manual](https://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_User_and_Programmers_Guide#Pagination).

There is a default limit of 20 in the number of entities retrieved by queryContext (and related convenience operations). If you want to increase that limit, use the `limit` URI parameter, e.g.

```
POST http://orion.lab.fi-ware.eu:1026/ngsi10/queryContext?limit=200
```

The absolute maximum limit is 1,000. If the query covers more than 1,000 result, the client have to retrieve the data in several chainned requests, using the offset parameters (see details in the above reference).

You can get a hint on how many entities are covered by the query using the `details` parameter, e.g:

```
POST http://orion.lab.fi-ware.eu:1026/ngsi10/queryContext?details=on
...
"errorCode": {
   "code": "200",
   "details": "Count: 2342",
   "reasonPhrase": "OK"
}
```

Comment: Ok this works with the REST application, thanks. But now, is pagination avaible in Wire Cloud NGSI API? how can I use this new option in Wire Cloud?

Comment: @Mest WireCloud supports making queries to Orion using pagination from version 0.6.5. Take a look to [the tutorial about how to use the Orion Context Broker from WireCloud](http://conwet.fi.upm.es/docs/display/wirecloud/Using+Orion+Context+Broker) and [the NGSI Javascript API reference](http://conwet.fi.upm.es/docs/display/wirecloud/NGSI+Javascript+API) documents for learning how to use that support.